# Why does using list.index(element) to update element at index not return proper index value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

```
test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for t in test:
    index = test.index(t)
    print(str(t)+ ' Index: '+ str(test.index(t)))
    print('\t\t'+str(test[test.index(t)]) + ' Index: ' + str(test.index(t)))
    test[index] = test[index] + 1
print(test)
```

```
Outputs:
1 Index: 0
        1 Index: 0
2 Index: 0
        2 Index: 0
3 Index: 0
        3 Index: 0
4 Index: 0
        4 Index: 0
5 Index: 0
        5 Index: 0
6 Index: 0
        6 Index: 0
7 Index: 0
        7 Index: 0
8 Index: 0
        8 Index: 0
9 Index: 0
        9 Index: 0
10 Index: 0
        10 Index: 0
[11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

For some reason, the index value test.index(t) is 0 every time it iterates through the test list?
but if I were to create my own index-tracking variable:

```
test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
index = 0
for t in test:
    print(str(t)+ ' Index: '+ str(test.index(t)))
    print('\t\t'+str(test[index]) + ' Index: ' + str(index))
    test[index] = test[index] + 1
    index += 1
print(test)
```

```
1 Index: 0
        1 Index: 0
2 Index: 0
        2 Index: 1
3 Index: 1
        3 Index: 2
4 Index: 2
        4 Index: 3
5 Index: 3
        5 Index: 4
6 Index: 4
        6 Index: 5
7 Index: 5
        7 Index: 6
8 Index: 6
        8 Index: 7
9 Index: 7
        9 Index: 8
10 Index: 8
        10 Index: 9
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Why does the list.index(element) not working properly. I have no absolutely no idea on how why this does not work. To mean it seems logical I grab the index of the element and then update it by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning the *proper* index value, as clearly documented, `list.index` returns **the first** index of an element. Because your list is a series of numbers increasing by *one*, and you *increment* the value by one, you are seeing this pattern. Perhaps printing `test` in your loop will demonstrate this more clearly:

```
In [2]: test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   ...: for t in test:
   ...:     index = test.index(t)
   ...:     print(str(t)+ ' Index: '+ str(test.index(t)))
   ...:     print('\t\t'+str(test[test.index(t)]) + ' Index: ' + str(test.index(t)))
   ...:     print('\t\t\t' + str(test))
   ...:     test[index] = test[index] + 1
   ...: print(test)
1 Index: 0
        1 Index: 0
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2 Index: 0
        2 Index: 0
            [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
3 Index: 0
        3 Index: 0
            [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
4 Index: 0
        4 Index: 0
            [4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
5 Index: 0
        5 Index: 0
            [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
6 Index: 0
        6 Index: 0
            [6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
7 Index: 0
        7 Index: 0
            [7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
8 Index: 0
        8 Index: 0
            [8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
9 Index: 0
        9 Index: 0
            [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
10 Index: 0
        10 Index: 0
            [10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

On the first iteration, you've increment `test[0] = test[0] + 1`. so `test[0]` has a value of **`2`**`. On your second iteration, then` test.index(1)`*returns`0`* because the` 2`is at index`0`. You then increment this again, and now` test[0] == 3`. On your *third* iteration, then you look for` test.index(3)`, which is again, at the 0th index... and so on and so forth...

Don't do this to begin with. Using `.index` in a loop is inefficient, it will create a quadratic time algorithm where you can trivially do it in linear time, e.g. by using your second approach, although, it would be more pythonic to use:

```
for index, t in enumerate(test):
    test[index] = t + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a loop will automatically go through each item in your list. Instead, remove the statement `test[index] = test[index] + 1` and your code should work just fine

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for t in test:
    index = test.index(t)
    print(str(t) + ' Index: ' + str(test.index(t)))
    print('\t\t' + str(test[test.index(t)]) + ' Index: ' + str(test.index(t)))
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You modify the test list by one every time, which means (given your list) each element becomes equal to next element.

If your list was different like [10, 20, 30, 40] you would not see the (seemingly incorrect) behavior.

Anyway, you better use `for index, num in enumerate(test)` for your purposes.